# PHP and ajax error

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to INSERT INTO a database using ajax. The table is updated by the php file, but I always get an error in ajax and the page could not be redirected to the results page.

My 'POST' function, in the html page is (it returns always the error alert):

```
function enviaFormDetalhes() { 
if (confirm("Tem a certeza que quer gravar os dados?")){
$.ajax( {
    type: 'post',
    url: 'php/f_propostas.php?tipo_acao=grava_nova_proposta&id_consulta='+getUrlVars()['id_consulta']+'&id_fornecedor='+getUrlVars()['id_fornecedor'],
    data: $("#form_detalhes_proposta").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Dados gravados com sucesso");
            location.href = 'f_editproposal.html?id_proposta='+data;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    } );      
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

The part of php file is: (This is working good, if I call i directly in the browser it returns me the lastinsertID):

```
case "grava_nova_proposta":

$ID_Fornecedor = $_GET['id_fornecedor'];
$ID_Consulta = $_GET['id_consulta'];
$DataRececao = $_POST['dt_proposta'];
$RefProposta = $_POST['ref_proposta'];
$DtValidade = $_POST['dt_validade'];
$DtCriacao_loop = gmdate('Y-m-d');
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fornecedores_propostas (
        id_fornecedor,
        id_contacto,
        id_consultaloop,
        datarecepcao,
        ref_proposta,
        validadeproposta)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($ID_Fornecedor, $ID_Contacto, $ID_ConsultaLoop, $DataRececao, $RefProposta, $DtValidade));
$Ultimo_ID = $conn->lastInsertId('id_proposta');
echo $Ultimo_ID;
break;
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: The alert message is: "Data-[object object]"

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` instead and look in the error console. The console might have related errors anyway.

Comment: Instead of alert do console.log(data); and check in Firebug and see what that object contains?

Comment: Okay, I've changed my code to put the console.log (check my message I've edited it). The pages refreshes after the error and I put an alert message to stop the paga refresh and in Chrome I get the message "error" in the console :(

Comment: I made a print screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoezfewkb0d9383/prtscrn.jpg

Comment: You can't log two variables at the same time like that. Do `console.log(errorThrown);` instead (`textStatus` is always "error").

Comment: I've done that and the console.log does'n return nothing. I'm sorry about my inexperience about this... I've been around with chrome and I found, in the Network-Response, that has "This Request Has no response data avaible" Is there a way to prevent the page refresh to see all the data before it refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
url: 'php/f_propostas.php,
data: tipo_acao=grava_nova_proposta&id_consulta='+getUrlVars()['id_consulta']+'&id_fornecedor='+getUrlVars()['id_fornecedor']+$("#form_detalhes_proposta").serialize(),
```

Comment: in mozilla firefox in firebug you can see the ajax URL and params which you are passing.so please can you check that and is possible can you share?

Comment: no buddy, when your ajax calls your page you will see url with php/f_propostas.php.

Comment: you will see URL under "console" tab

Comment: Let's see if I get it now. Is this? : https://www.dropbox.com/s/43pra55e2vzxo1i/prtscr3.jpg

Comment: In my ajax I put the "async: false," line and it enters in the success function. Is this correct? But now, after the alert message, the page doesn't redirect to the new one (location.href = 'f_editproposal.html?id_proposta='+data;) Any idea? Thanks